# SystemJS is not importing

Tags: typescript, systemjs

Unable to use Typescript with the SystemJS. This is my test example:

---

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "System",
    "target": "es2015",
    "outFile": "./lib/mylib.js"
  },

  "include": [
    "./src/mylib.ts"
  ]
}
```

---

lib/mylib.ts

```
export default class MyClass {
    constructor(public readonly msg: string) { }

    public print() {
        console.log(this.msg)
    }
}
```

---

test.html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/6.3.1/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/6.3.1/extras/named-register.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/mylib.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

---

lib/mylib.js

```
System.register("mylib", [], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var MyClass;
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            MyClass = class MyClass {
                constructor(msg) {
                    this.msg = msg;
                }
                print() {
                    console.log(this.msg);
                }
            };
            exports_1("default", MyClass);
        }
    };
});
```

---

test.js

```js
System.import('mylib').then(() => {
    let mc = new MyClass('My message')
    mc.print()
})
```

---

Getting an error: `test.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined at test.js:2`

I try to use SystemJS as I need to load MyClass locally (without CORS). I would use ES6 modules but module imports are not permitted locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem that I could spot that the browser will try to search for the `MyClass` on the entire global object to see whether it stores it. But SystemJS loads the modules dynamically and returns them inside the promise, thus you will include it like this:

```
System.import('mylib').then((importedObject) => {
  const MyClass = importedObject.default
  let mc = new MyClass('My message')
  mc.print()
})
```

That will simply Return you the `importedObject` and then you can specify which import you want to use. In this case you want to use the default export as it stores your `MyClass`.